# Написать структуру которая принимает много контактов

Tags: c#

У меня есть структура которая хранит контакты(Имя, фамилия, номер телефона, адрес). Как сделать структуру которая будет принимать столько контаков сколько пользователь хочет, и будет их принимать и распечатает в консоли

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Как вас зовут ?");
    string first_name = Console.ReadLine();
    
    Console.WriteLine("Как ваша фамилия ?");
    string last_name = Console.ReadLine();
    
    Console.WriteLine("Скажите ваш номер телефона");
    int phone_number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    
    Console.WriteLine("По какому адрес вы проживаете ?");
    string addres = Console.ReadLine();
            
    Contact info = new Contact(first_name,last_name,phone_number,addres);
    info.WriteInfo();
}

struct Contact
{   
    string first_name;
    string last_name;
    int phone_number;
    string addres;

    public Contact(string first_name, string last_name, int phone_number, string addres)
    {
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.phone_number = phone_number;
        this.addres = addres;
    }
    public void WriteInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Вас зовут {0} {1} \nВаш телефонный номер {2} \nВаш адрес {3}",first_name,last_name,phone_number,addres); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну сделайте класс, где будет храниться список `List<Contact>`

Comment: `Как сделать структуру` почему именно структуру, а не просто список?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ContactList
    {
        private List<Contact> _contacts = new List<Contact>();

        public void AddContact(string first_name, string last_name, int phone_number, string addres)
        {
            _contacts.Add(new Contact(first_name, last_name, phone_number, addres));
        }

        public void PrintList()
        {
            _contacts.ForEach(contact => Console.WriteLine(contact));

        }



    }
```

в Main

```
 var contactList = new ContactList();
 contactList.AddContact(first_name, last_name, phone_number, addres);
 contactList.AddContact(first_name, last_name, phone_number, addres);
        
 contactList.PrintList();
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(contact)` выведет в консоль что? Почему `AddContact` принимает аргументы класса `Contact`, а не экземпляр? Тогда уж `CreateContact` должно называться. Почему список контакотов недоступен извне? Почему автор просит структуру, а вы ему написали класс? Сомнительный ответ.

Comment: @aepot Автор сам себе же ответ пишет, похоже ))  А классом я его видимо сбил. Просто не помню - у структуры могут быть методы?

Comment: @CrazyElf от этого ответ менее сомнительным не стал :)